# React sort list by value and then alphabetically

Tags: reactjs, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of items by their value (stored in Firebase) first (items with the same value have the same color), and then alphabetically (so the green items should be in alphabetical order, the yellow ones too..). I tried using || and also a.localeCompare(b), but nothing seems to work. It is either alphabetically or by value (random), but nether both.

[image]

This is my code for sorting it by value:

```
.sort((a, b) => a.daysLeftForNextPurchase > b.daysLeftForNextPurchase ? 1 : -1)
.map((shoppingItemObject, index) => {
 const shopIndex = shoppingList[0].items.indexOf(
 shoppingItemObject,
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this and it works perfectly!

```
.sort((a, b) =>
 a.daysLeftForNextPurchase > b.daysLeftForNextPurchase
 ? 1
 : a.daysLeftForNextPurchase === b.daysLeftForNextPurchase
 ? a.shoppingListItemName > b.shoppingListItemName
 ? 1
 : -1
 : -1,
)
```